# Adding a custom UI component as a panel titleIcon (should be easy, I'm kind of a newbie)

Tags: apache-flex, class, actionscript, panel

The concept of this seems easy, but I'm having trouble getting it right and can't find anything to help me on this.

I have a panel I need to perform a drag and drop operation on, but I only want to perform that if the user mouses down on a particular area of the panel. I can add an Icon to the panel by doing this:

```
[Embed("/img/icon.png")]
[Bindable]
public var dragIcon:Class;

newPanel.titleIcon = dragIcon;
```

But what I really want to add is a box, which I can then add my listeners to for the drag and mouse down like I do on some canvases created in actionscript like so

```
var tempBox:Box = new Box;
tempBox.x=0;
tempBox.y=0;
tempBox.width = 20;
tempBox.height = 44;
tempBox.setStyle("horizontalAlign","center");
tempBox.setStyle("verticalAlign","middle");
tempBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,over);
tempBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,out);
tempBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownAnswer);
var tempImg:Image = new Image();
tempImg.source = grabbableItem;
tempBox.addChild(tempImg);
myCanvas.addChild(tempBox);
```

So what do I need to do to use that tempBox and turn it into a class to be used as my panels titleIcon?

Edit 12/29/09:
So I came up with something where I'm extending the panel class (shown below) but all this is really doing is covering up the icon with something I can access publicly. I'm sure there's a better way out there right?

```
package custClass
{
    import mx.containers.Box;
    import mx.containers.Panel;
    import mx.controls.Image;

    public class DragPanel extends Panel
    {
        [Bindable] public var iconBox:Box = new Box();

        [Embed("../img/doc_page.png")] [Bindable] public var grabbableItem:Class;

        public function DragPanel()
        {
            super();
        }
        override protected function createChildren():void{
            super.createChildren();

            iconBox.x = 10
            iconBox.y = 4
            iconBox.width = 20;
            iconBox.height = 20;
            iconBox.setStyle("horizontalAlign","center");
            iconBox.setStyle("verticalAlign","middle");
            iconBox.setStyle("borderStyle","solid");
            iconBox.setStyle("backgroundColor",0x000000);
            var tempImg:Image = new Image();
            tempImg.source = grabbableItem;
            iconBox.addChild(tempImg);
            this.rawChildren.addChild(iconBox);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1/7/10 (or 16 according to my windows mobile phones text messages):
Using Chaims help from below here is my new answer.

Create a box mxml component like Chaim says but also add the following script block to it.

```
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.Application;
            [Embed("/img/doc_page.png")]
            [Bindable]
            public var grabbableItem:Class;

            public function init():void{
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,Application.application.mouseDownSection);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,Application.application.over);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,Application.application.out);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
```

This adds in all the event listeners I want on the Box that will be used as my icon. Now just add the box as an Icon and it's good to go.

```
panel.titleIcon = DraggableBox;
```

I guess since it's a separate mxml component it is now a class, though I don't think I understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Panel expecting titleIcon property value to be a IFactory and create an instance by himself.

Make your box a component (lets name it DraggableBox.mxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    x="0" y="0" width="20" height="44"
    horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <mx:Image source="{grabbableItem}"/>
</mx:Box>
```

And assign it to titleIcon:

```
<mx:Panel titleIcon="{DraggableBox}" >
...
</mx:Panel>
```

If you want do it in ActionScript use ClassFactory:

```
panel.titleIcon = new ClassFactory(DraggableBox);
```

Comment: Thanks chaim, I see this is your first activity on SO, so really, thanks for taking the time to register just to provide me with this answer. I think I'm very close to getting it to work but I'm getting a 1067 error (Implicit coercion of a value of type mx.core:ClassFactory to an unrelated type Class) when I run the AS "panel.titleIcon = new ClassFactory(DraggableBox);" Any idea of what to do there?

Comment: OK I got it now, it's not "panel.titleIcon = new ClassFactory(DraggableBox);" it's actually just plain "panel.titleIcon = DraggableBox;" Thanks again.